# Self Signed certificate throws 404 not found error on AWS Route53 domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

I have imported a self signed certificate in AWS Certificate Manager for domain *.example.dev.

My application is deployed on elastic beanstalk which works when accessed through the elastic beanstalk environment link.

But when I use Amazon Route 53 to route DNS traffic for abc.example.dev to my existing Elastic Beanstalk environment and go to abc.example.dev, I get a "404 not found error".

I don't know what is going wrong.

Do I need to have the example.dev domain registered inside Route53 registered domains as well. At the moment my route53 doesn't have any registered domains.

Answer (score 0):

`abc.example.dev` must point at the load balancer (the ALB) URL associated with your Elastic Beanstalk deployment. The `example.dev` domain doesn't necessarily have to be registered with route53 - it could be registered with any DNS provider. You just need to set up a CNAME record that points at your Elastic Beanstalk environment. See [these docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html) for more info.